# jQuery hides everything although I tell it to show

Tags: jquery

Kind of hard to explain this problem in the title...

I would like to show the `.rowOptions` of the row entered by the mouse, but also hide all other instances of `.rowOptions`.

I have the following code, but it hides all elements. It seems like it executes the `show()` line before the `hide()` line.

How can I solve this?

```
$(".container_12").live('mouseenter', function() { 

    $(".rowOptions").hide(); 
    $(this).children(".rowOptions").show();

});
```

The markup is:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div />
    <div />
    <div />
    <div class="rowOptions" style="display: none"; />
</div>
```

Comment: the markup is:

<div class="container_12">
<div />
<div />
<div />
<div class="rowOptions" style="display: none"; />
</div>

Comment: it works perfectly fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/VMcVP/

Comment: Maybe you should have valid markup. no short close on divs `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your selector is wrong. I'm willing to bet that `$(this).children('.rowOptions')` is returning 0 elements, and thus nothing is being shown.

Without knowing how your HTML is setup, it's hard to say for sure. I would suggest logging the count of items you get back or throwing an alert:

```
 alert($(this).children('.rowOptions').length);
```

Comment: Even better, use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: It returns the needed elements, because when I remove `hide()` it shows what I need.

Comment: Of course it would, since nothing is being hidden. According to the markup you posted above, there is no `rowOptions` element inside `container_12`.

Comment: I guess the syntax isn't correct, but how about: 

  `$(".rowOptions").not(this.children(".rowOptions")).hide(); 
$(this).children(".rowOptions").show();`

Comment: Then it's probably something else. Any chance you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Tejs Well, there is - I just abbreviated the divs. <div /> = <div></div>

Comment: Can you verify the relationship is correct? `$(this).find('.rowOption').html()` is what you expect right?

Comment: Do you have a conflicting mouseleave handler?